# Conflict beween pgfplots, babel package and babel tikzlibrary

Tags: pgfplots, babel

I came across a strange error today with a simple beamer frame that I am pretty sure worked a few weeks ago.

It seems to boil down (again) to active characters, which is something that `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` aims to fix. But here it is the other way around: if the library is used, it produces an error (`File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@addplotimpl@table@fromfile`), while there is no problem when it is not used...

Interestingly, if the `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` is removed, everything goes smoothly.

P.S. Older related posts do not seem to answer the problem...

This one deals with `tikzmark`:
[Clash between tikzmark, babel package (french) and babel tikzlibrary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335485/clash-between-tikzmark-babel-package-french-and-babel-tikzlibrary)

This one deals with `etoolbox`: [Conflict between french option, babel package, babel tikzlibrary and etoolbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540079/conflict-between-french-option-babel-package-babel-tikzlibrary-and-etoolbox-pa)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % No problem if commented

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
   a,b,c,d,e
   1,2,3,4,5
   1,2,3,4,5
   1,2,3,4,5
   1,2,3,4,5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} % Also no problem if commented!?
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot table[col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex, y=a]{test.csv};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} % Also no problem if commented!?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you change `french` to a different language it also works

Comment: Adding `shorthands=off` to the babel options also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `french` babel package has a lot of incompatibilities due to the "activation" and redefinition of some special characters. In this case, what bites you is the activation of `;`. Although the `babel` Ti*k*Z library suffices sometimes, it clearly fails inside a `frame`.

I see three possible solution:

1. Use `lualatex`. In this case, the special spacing needed by `;:` it's done using the LUA engine, and your example works out-of-the-box.
2. Disable the `;` shorthand at the start of the frame, adding `\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\shorthandoff{;}}` in the preamble; maybe in the future you need to add also `:` to the list (for what I know, `babel-french` activates `;:!?`).
3. Disable shorthands for good with `\usepackage[french, shorthand=off]{babel}`

The solution (1) is the one that preserves all the special spacing rules...

Comment: Didn't know about the first point, very interesting! The other ones are inappropriate since the spacing rules should be kept. Still, I'm wondering what happened: disabling shorthands within `tikzpicture` is precisely the goal of the `babel` TikZ library, and I'm pretty sure it worked not so long ago. Maybe some recent update broke something (I'm updating TeX Live regularly).

Comment: Also, adding `[fragile]` as a frame option works...

Comment: You can check in `overleaf` where you can use the past years versions --- if you can find a regression you can submit an issue on the `beamer` github.

Comment: I tried 2014, 2020, 2021 and it fails on everyone...

Comment: Hmm, weird. I compiled the failing document a few weeks ago without problem... Anyway, I guess I'll use `lualatex` (despite it being so slow with externalized tikzpictures...), so I'm accepting your answer.